DXF file lines are out of order
I am a bit confused about the DXF file format. I have this file that has a bunch of geometrical paths. And looks something like the attached image when imported into most other softwares. Even my laser software is able to get out the complete geometrical polygons allowing me to move the pieces around.

Now when I read the DXF file manually in python I get a ton of line segments. And I originally had hoped they were roughly in some wrap order but no they are all over the place.
My algorithm assumes it can build a polygon from lines that are next to each other in the list. It checks in case the start and end points happen to be flipped and even checks if the next line could go at the start or end of the polygon. Still I end up with a mess.

You can see a lot of geometry is just gone since its lines weren't next to the lines in the polygon in the file. Sometimes it is able to read part of the geometry but then it cant find the next line.
As near as I can tell although some lines in the DXF file are in order but most of them are just random. Which means a pretty expensive algorithm is needed to take the raw line data and interpret it into polygons.
Is there no way to get the dxf file read in a way that the lines are in order with ezdxf? Does this file format just not allow for defined line order?
